# Simplifying a `match` using a Rust macro

Tags: rust, macros

There are many question functions (hundreds), and each may have a different type. For each question I want to run a `run_question` function, which shows how long that function took, and print it's output.

I'm trying to shorten the following `match` expression with a Rust macro (writing `run_question` 100s of times does make the code rather long):

```rust
fn run_question<T: std::fmt::Display>(question_func: fn() -> T) {
  let begin = Instant::now();
  let output: T = question_func();
  let elapsed_secs = begin.elapsed().as_micros() as f32 / 1e6;
  println!("{}", output);
  println!("{:.6}s taken", elapsed_secs);
}

fn q1() -> u8 { /* ... */ }
fn q2() -> u32 { /* ... */ }
fn q3() -> u64 { /* ... */ }
fn q4() -> String { /* ... */ }

fn main() {
  // ...
  match question_num {
    1 => run_question(q1), 2 => run_question(q2), 3 => run_question(q3), 4 => run_question(q4),
    _ => {
      println!("Question doesn't exist.");
    },
  }
}
```

I have no experience in writing macros, and attempted the following which doesn't exactly work. It gives the error:

```
error: variable 'question_num' is still repeating at this depth
```

I'm rather stumped too how I can print the `Question doesn't exist.` as a default case.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! run_questions {
  ( $chosen_question: expr, $( $question_num: expr, $question_mod: expr ), * ) => {
    {
      if $chosen_question == $question_num {
        run_question($question_mod::solve);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The way I'd like to use it, is (or anything just as short is fine as well):

```rust
run_questions!(question_num, 1, q1, 2, q2, 3, q3, 4, q4);
```

I read a bit of the Rust book, but there aren't exactly that many examples of macros.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: would you consider other option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than many `if` statements, I just reproduced the `match` statement
with a repetition `$( ... )*` for all the available branches.
It seems to behave like the extensive `match` expression.

```rust
macro_rules! run_questions {
    ( $chosen_question: expr, $( $question_num: expr, $question_mod: expr ), * ) => {
        match $chosen_question {
          $($question_num => run_question($question_mod),)*
          _ => {
                println!("Question doesn't exist.");
          }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message explained:

```
macro_rules! run_questions {
    ($chosen_question: expr, $($question_num: expr, $question_mod: expr),*) => {{
```

In the above pattern you have a repetition with the `*` operator that involves variables `$question_num` and `$question_mod`

```
        if $chosen_question == $question_num {
            run_question($question_mod::solve);
        }
```

In the corresponding code, you can't use `$question_num` and `$question_mod` directly: since they are repeated they potentially have more than one value and which one should the compiler use here? Instead, you need to tell the compiler to repeat the block of code that uses these variables. This is done by surrounding the repeated code block with `$()` and adding the `*` operator:

```
        $(if $chosen_question == $question_num {
            run_question($question_mod::solve);
        })*
```

Although as pointed out by @prog-fh's answer, better to use a `match` in the macro, same as in the straight code:

```
match $chosen_question {
    $($question_num => run_question ($question_mod::solve),)*
    _ => println!("Question doesn't exist.")
};
```